# Place image in absolute position independently from text

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I am using the Fancy CV tempate and I would like to put an image on the top right corner.

I managed to do that using :

```
\begin{picture}(50,50)
\put(335,10){\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=1]{img/photoCircle}}}
\end{picture}
```

Which produces :

[image: Title with photo]

But this moves the rest of the page.

It should be like this :

[image: Without photo]

So I was wondering, is there any way to force images and text to be on different layers and force the image to be "floating" (not moving the text)

Comment: Can you `\smash` the `picture`?  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235425/moderncv-picture-below-name-and-line-in-casual-style

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34929/89417)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `tikzpagenodes` package is specifically designed for this purpose.  You can put just about anything you want in the node, albeit that for more complicated structures it can take a little digging to find out how.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north east)}]
\node[anchor=north east,xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: As of late 2022, `\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}` does not seem to be required/working anymore. Instead I got the snippet working with `\usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{positioning}`.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with JPi's answer, but at least currently, the tikz package contain all the functions in this code, so just using package tikz as below is OK.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north east)}]
\node[anchor=north east,xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```